# Can I boot Android on the LG Arena KM 900?

Tags: installation, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I have searched (hopefully well enough!) on the internet to see if we can load Android on the LG Arena KM 900.

Though there was this forum which kind of talked about it, it was still not clear as to how to do it.

http://androidarena.pytalhost.net/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=76&pageNo=6&s=12839d124f983ac19ea9e43226073557b26abf3f

Has any one tried this?

Appreciate the time taken to answer my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd also like to add that porting Android to a phone is a herculean effort because the hardware needs to be reverse-engineered from the original OS. Even if an official port of Android exists for this CPU, the kernel needs a lot of work. Even a well-maintained and coordinated effort like the ports to the various HTC WinMo phones have not resulted in usable Android releases for day-to-day use for all phones yet. As far as I know, only two older models are fully supported (the Vogue and the Kaiser). If you need the phone as more than an experimental Android test-drive, I can only recommend buying a comes-with-Android phone.

Obviously this is not meant to diss the developers of these projects, as they are doing an amazing job in a difficult situation, and there is steady progress. Just don't hold your breath, they are doing it in their spare time and will need a lot of that :)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I'll spend some time on the forum and see where we are. Maybe someday, switching OS on the mobile will be a lot easier :)

Answer (score 2):

You've already found the forum for the main project to port Android to the LG KM900 at http://androidarena.pytalhost.net/

All of their effort towards porting Android to the KM900 is being tracked on this Google Code page http://code.google.com/p/arenoid/ their project status page doesn't look like they've managed this yet http://code.google.com/p/arenoid/wiki/ProjectStatus

So, unfortunately it doesn't look like this is possible yet. I think that your best bet to speed up the process will be to visit that forum and Google Code section and volunteer to help them out in their efforts.

Comment: Thanks GA. Very unfortunate that I can only select any one as the answer. Both your responses have been very helpful and guiding. Thank You

Answer (score -2):

I have been following that Google code page for ages when I had my Lg Arena, and they still have no success since early 2010. Android on the arena, no success.